# Joint distribution for an event that occurs conditioned on another event

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose I have the event $Y$,

$$
Y = \begin{cases}
    y_1,& p\\
    y_2,& (1-p)
\end{cases}
$$

and the event $X$ that only occurs when $Y=2$,

$$
\{X|Y=y_2\} = \begin{cases}
    x_1,& q\\
    x_2,& (1-q)
\end{cases}
$$

Then given $x$ occurs we know that $y=y_2$,

\begin{array}{l|ll}
P(y|x) &y_1 &y_2 \\ \hline
x_1 &0 &1 \\
x_2 &0 &1
\end{array}

and given $y=y_1$, we know $x$ didn't occur,

\begin{array}{l|ll}
P(x|y) &x_1 &x_2 \\ \hline
y_1 &0 &0 \\
y_2 &q &(1-q)
\end{array}

And the joint pmf can be calculated multiplying $p(y|x)$ with $p(x)$.

Where $p(x) = p(x|y=y_1)p(y_1) + p(x|y=y_2)p(y_2)$.
Since $p(x|y=y_1) = 0$, we have,

$$
p(x) =\begin{cases}
    (1-p)q,& x=x_1\\
    (1-p)(1-q),& x=x_2
\end{cases}
$$

Something doesn't seem right. If I find the joint pmf, and then try to find the marginal of $Y$ from the the joint, I have that $p(y=y_1) = 0$.

Did I do something wrong here? It seems to be related to the fact that $x$ doesn't occur during the event $y=y_1$. How would I find the joint pmf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation for $p(x)$ adds up to $1-p$ when we need it to add up to $1$. The issue is that you are considering only $x_1$ and $x_2$ as possibilities for $X$, but not considering the third valid possibility, which is "$X$ does not occur", which has probability $p$.